Cross-References to a separate Lyx document
I need to cross-references tables from one Lyx document to another one. I tried to do so by selecting the reference file in the Document Setting option, but I got a broken link. Any idea on how to fix this?
Thanks!
I tried to do so by selecting the reference file in the Document Setting option, but I got a broken link.
